# Create a branch when "a branch of the same name already exists"?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I already read topics like [How to correctly close a feature branch in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237222/how-to-correctly-close-a-feature-branch-in-mercurial)

But I want remove branches reference.

Example

```
hg branch my-branch
hg commit -m "commit" --close-branch
hg branches -c
```

**hg branches -c** displays my-branch in the list. And I can't create a new branch named **my-branch**.

```
hg branch my-branch
```

Mercurial shows me an error :

```
abort: a branch of the same name already exists
```

Do you know how to remove branch reference definitively ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg help branch`

> ...
>
> options:
>
> -f --force set branch name even if it shadows an existing branch
>
> ...